# I want help in tets script

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good morning, guys. I'm working on my exam script end.

I have some problem with it: my script dose not work. It's about to calculate correct answers in my test, but I'm new in JS and I'm making some tests to do it correctly.

Please help me with it.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var correct_ansawers= new array(4,9,16,25,36);
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
function show()
{


   if(x[0].value=4)
   {
      alert("4");
   }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>    
<input type="radio" value=4 name="true" onclick="show();"/>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: replace to `new Array(...)`

Comment: You may also want to use http://jsfiddle.net for your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes:

1) it should be `new Array(...)`, not `new array(...)`.
2) it should be `if(x[0] == 4){...}`, not `if(x[0] = 4){...}`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var correct_ansawers = new Array(4, 9, 16, 25, 36);
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        function show() {
            if (x[0].value == 4) {
                alert("4");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" value=4 name="true" onclick="show();"/>

</body>
</html>
```